# ACH Payment Processing for flutter app (with split payment support)

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, braintree, payment-processing

I have searched far and wide, and I cannot for the life of me find documentation on a payment processor that can accept and split ACH payments to different vendors on a flutter app.

Braintree, for example, has ACH support, but I found that it has to be implemented with their custom javascript v3 SDK. Stripe Connect seems to have the features I need, but I see no documentation in the Stripe pub package that shows how to accept an ACH transfer.

Support and documentation for credit card payments seems to be solid on all fronts, but I've reached a dead end when it comes to getting an ACH payments solution. Not sure if I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to stitch together some pieces of this yourself, but here are some pointers to accomplish this with Stripe:

- Review the ACH guide for collecting bank account details via the API [here](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts)
- To get the `token` you need you can use [`createTokenWithBankAccount`](https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment#bank-account-params-object)  (more docs [here](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/blob/experimental-connect/website/docs-md/createtokenwithbankaccount.md))
- Review the docs for "Separate Charges and Transfers" payment flow to see how to use Connect to split this payment to multiple vendors [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers)